# How to use variable defined in one php tag in another php tag?

Tags: php, javascript

I wrote a php page which has two php tags and one script tag inside it .

```
<?php
$value = $_GET['hash'];
?>
<script>
function execute(){
<?php
$readfile = file($value);
for ($k=0;$k<=count($readfile)-1;$k++){
$cmd = $readfile[$k];
echo $cmd;}
?>
}
</script>
```

I want to use $value inside another php tag ( like above it has the file I want to open ), but I am not able to do it.Is the scope of variable limited to one php tag ? if yes how can I solve this problem Please help

Comment: Have you got this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works perfectly. The variables in one PHP tag is accessible from all other tags, unless you define them inside a PHP function.

The reason you are not seeing the echo on the screen is because the echo prints to the Javascript function.

If you view the source of the generated page, the file contents will be there.

Try this:

```
function execute(){
    <?php
    $readfile = file($value);
    for ($k=0;$k<=count($readfile)-1;$k++){
        $cmd = $readfile[$k];
    ?>
        alert( <?php echo $cmd; ?> );
    <?php
    }
    ?>
}

execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

if $value is a get then you don't need to access it as a file, it should just be a short string.

just above line 7 (the one with $readfile = file...
type:

```
echo "alert(The hash value is: ".$value.")";
```

This will make an alert display (as it is in a script tag)
p.s you should have  in your opening tag

Comment: $value holds the name of the file I want to open.I tried doing echo in the second php tag to display what $value holds...but its not working

Comment: The problem is that you did not do any investigation beyond noticing that "its not working". A simple `View Source` operation from your browser would have shown you immediately that `echo $value` worked just fine.

Comment: This is rude ... i did investigate but i wasnt able to get my value working there ... i needed a way to solve this problem

Comment: You can yourself see how everyone is having different opinions , only one person said my code was right ..